# Why does this code to stash babylonjs meshes cause an error?

Tags: coffeescript, babylonjs

I am loading a .obj file containing meshes of numerals. I want to stash each mesh against its name so that I can create instances later.

The code works fine if I remove the line that is actually stashing the mesh in 'originals'. However when I leave it in it appears that an exception is thrown and caught inside Babylon with the message "BJS - [12:17:50]: Unable to load assets from /threedee/InputMonoNumerics.obj: Error in onSuccess callback".

```
originals = {}
BABYLON.SceneLoader.LoadAssetContainer(assetPath, assetName, scene, (container) ->
  container.addAllToScene()
  for i in[0...scene.meshes.length]
    mesh = scene.meshes[i]
    if (mesh.name.startsWith('numeral'))
      character = mesh.name.charAt('numeral_'.length)
      originals["_#{character}"] = mesh
      console.log("This line is never reached.")
      mesh
)
```

This is coffeescript source - but the transpiled code looks exactly as you would expect

Comment: Looks like something is throwing an error in the callback but it's swallowed by the library. Maybe `mesh.name` is a non string? Either `console.log` everything, or use a `try...catch` inside the callback to see the original error

Answer (score 1):

Yes - much thanks to caffeinated.tech - obviously (now you come to mention it) try and catch to see the underlying error!

... which was that the debug statements I had put in to help were throwing an error by calling JSON.stringify on Babylon Mesh objects - which are circular - I think because they have a reference to their parent which of course has a reference back to the Mesh.

It is no longer clear what the original problem was - but that's not a problem.